# how to get number from string without regex

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, information-extraction

**Without using rege**x, is there a way to get number from a string in JavaScript?

For example, if input is `"id is 12345"`, then I want `12345` number in output.

I know a lot of regex solutions, but I am looking for a non-regex tidy solution.

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:regex] if you don't want a regex solution?

Answer (score 2):

Iterate characters and check whether they are in a set of numbers:

```js
const str = 'id is 12345 or 54321';

const set = new Set([...'0123456789']);

const nums = [];
let start = -1;

for (let i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
  const c = str[i];
  if (set.has(c)) {
    if(start === -1 ){
      start = i;
    }
  } else {
    start > -1 && nums.push(+str.slice(start, i));
    start = -1;
  }
}

console.log(nums);
```

If you want the fastest solution use Unmitigated's `c >= '0' && c <= '9'` and `String::slice()`:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1">

const str = "abc def 12345 xyz 987".repeat(1000000);

// @benchmark Unmitigated
{
  let res = [], curr = '';
  for (const c of str + ' ') {
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') // add || c === '-' (to handle negatives)
      curr += c;
    else if (curr)
      res.push(+curr), curr = '';
      // use BigInt(curr) to handle larger numbers
  }
  res
}

// @benchmark Alexander

{
  const set = new Set([...'0123456789']);

  const nums = [];
  let start = -1;

  for (let i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
    const c = str[i];
    if (set.has(c)) {
      if(start === -1 ){
        start = i;
      }
    } else {
      start > -1 && nums.push(+str.slice(start, i));
      start = -1;
    }
  }
  nums
}

// @benchmark Unmitigated + String::slice()
{
  let res = [], start = -1;
  for (let i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
    const c = str[i];
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
      if(start === -1 ){
        start = i;
      }
    } else {
      start > -1 && res.push(+str.slice(start, i));
      start = -1;
    }
  }
  res
}


</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over all the characters and build up numbers from consecutive digits.

Here is one solution that works for multiple numbers (formed only using the characters 0-9).

```js
const str = "abc def 12345 xyz 987";
let res = [], curr = '';
for (const c of str + ' ') {
  if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') // add || c === '-' (to handle negatives)
    curr += c;
  else if (curr)
    res.push(+curr), curr = '';
    // use BigInt(curr) to handle larger numbers
}
console.log(res);
```